# getAudioMode[0] error

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am developing a game and playing audio sounds using SoundPool and `MediaPlayer`. Every time when any audio sound plays, it shows error in LogCat.

```
public class MusicSoundResources {

    private static final String CLASS_TAG = "SoundResources";

    private static MusicSoundResources _instance;
    public static HashMap<String, MediaPlayer> mSoundPoolMap;
    private static AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    private static Context mContext;

    public MusicSoundResources() {

    }

    public static void initSounds(Context theContext) {
         mContext = theContext;
         mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<String, MediaPlayer>();
         mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         loadSounds();
    }

    private static void loadSounds()    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put("swallowed", MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.swallowed));
    }

    public static void playSound(String soundTrackIndex, boolean loop) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mSoundPoolMap.get(soundTrackIndex);
        float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mediaPlayer.setVolume(streamVolume, streamVolume);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(loop);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

These are two logs which display:

```
05-31 15:02:56.400: ERROR/AudioTrack(2384): getAudioMode[0]
05-31 15:02:56.400: ERROR/AudioR2VS(2384): The 11025 sample rate is not supported by R2VS solution.
```

Same problem occurs when I use SoundPool.

Tell me what is the supported sample rate.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth:                                               SoundPool mSoundPool = new SoundPool(50, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);                                                                 HashMap<String, Integer> mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();                                                         mSoundPoolMap.put("fire", mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.fire, 1));                                                                mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get("fire"), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1);

Comment: You should have edited your post... I did it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer for this. This error comes when we play sounds of bit rate higher than 11025 Hz. This is an an internal error of android media player.

Answer (score 0):

Tha last parameter of the `play()`-method is a `float`, not an `int`:

> public final int play (int soundID,
>   float leftVolume, float rightVolume,
>   int priority, int loop, **float rate**)

This should work:

```
mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get("fire"), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1.0);
```

Comment: But this error is still coming:                                    05-31 17:02:09.091: ERROR/AudioTrack(20897): getAudioMode[0]

Comment: I can't see any `getAudioMode`-Array in your code. Please post all code that is nessesary (edit your post).

Comment: @ Lukas Knuth: I have edited my post. This is the complete class which i am using to play audio sounds. I am not using getAudioMode, this comes in logcat when any audio sound plays. Hope you will get problem now.